# Data from one MySQL table to be used in another table

Tags: php, mysql, select, inner-join

**SUMMARY:**

When displaying the data from TABLE2, replace the number in TABLE2's TOPIC field with the associated TOPIC_NAME from TABLE1.

**DETAILS:**

I have 2 tables in the same MySQL DB. I need help populating the array from TABLE1 to be used by TABLE2.  If it matters, I'm using PDO.

No UPDATE or INSERT... just display the words instead of the number.

Do I nest the TABLE2 Foreach display loop within TABLE1's Foreach loop?

or...

Can I populate an array with the TOPIC data first and then execute the TABLE1 Foreach display loop?

or...

Can I just reference the TOPIC_NAME from TABLE1 using the data from TABLE2 without creating an array?

or...

???

============================

**TABLE1** is a list of topics.

TABLE1 Syntax:

TOPIC_NUM,TOPIC_NAME

Sample Record from TABLE1:

1,Topic1

2,Topic2

etc...

============================

**TABLE2** is a list of individual people and associated data.

TABLE2 Syntax:

ID,NAME,STATE,TOPIC,YEAR

Sample Record from TABLE2:

1,John Smith,MA,2,2005

2,Jane Doe,AZ,1,2009

etc...

============================

FYI:  In the Sample Record above, the number after the State abbreviation is the TOPIC.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


// TABLE1
$tablename1 = 'topics';
$topics_col1 = 'TOPIC_NUM';
$topics_col2 = 'TOPIC_NAME';

// TABLE2
$tablename2 = 'people';
$items_col1 = 'NAME';
$items_col2 = 'STATE';
$items_col3 = 'TOPIC';
$items_col4 = 'YEAR';


$items_q = "SELECT $items_col1, $items_col2, $items_col3 FROM $tablename2";
$items = $db->query($items_q);

foreach ($items as $items_row) {
?>

<h2><?php 
/*


THIS IS WHERE THE TOPIC_NAME FROM TABLE1 SHOULD DISPLAY


*/
?></h2>

<p>
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col1];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col2];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col3];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col4];?>
</p>

<?php   
} // end FOREACH

    $db = null; // close the database connection

} // end TRY
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<span class="error">ERROR:</span><br />'.$e->getMessage() . "<br />";
    die();
} // end CATCH

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.ID, a.NAME, a.STATE, b.TOPIC_NAME , a.YEAR
FROM    table2 a
        INNER JOIN table1 b
            ON  a.topic = b.topic_num
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7be9/1)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is the final version of this script.  I have included a commented section that shows the alternative coding method for the query using the "dot" method.

I have tested this script (using both methods) and it functions perfectly.

```
<?php 

try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");


// TABLE1
$tablename1 = 'topics';
$topics_col1 = 'TOPIC_NUM';
$topics_col2 = 'TOPIC_NAME';

// TABLE2
$tablename2 = 'people';
$items_col1 = 'NAME';
$items_col2 = 'STATE';
$items_col3 = 'TOPIC';
$items_col4 = 'YEAR';


$items_q = "SELECT $items_col1, $items_col2, $items_col3, $items_col4, $topics_col2 
FROM $tablename2 
JOIN $tablename1 on ($items_col3 = $topics_col1)";

/* ALTERNATE METHOD FOR QUERY

(*No need for all of the vars above using this method.)
$items_q = "SELECT $tablename2.NAME, $tablename2.STATE, $tablename2.TOPIC, $tablename2.YEAR, $tablename1.TOPIC_NAME 
FROM $tablename2 
INNER JOIN $tablename1 on ($tablename2.TOPIC = $tablename1.TOPIC_NUM)";

*/

$items = $db->query($items_q);

foreach ($items as $items_row) {
?>

<h2><?php echo $items_row[$topics_col2];?></h2>

<p>
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col1];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col2];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col3];?>
<br />
<?php echo $items_row[$items_col4];?>
</p>

<?php   
} // end FOREACH

    $db = null; // close the database connection

} // end TRY
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '<span class="error">ERROR:</span><br />'.$e->getMessage() . "<br />";
    die();
} // end CATCH

?>
```